# RFM analysis - using ddply in R. Missing column

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use the code mentioned for RFM modelling in R from the blog [here](http://www.dataapple.net/?p=133). However, grouping the data frame into “Buy” and “No Buy” has not been explained clearly. As a result, when I try to execute the function `getPercentages`, I get error like:

> object "Buy" not found.

I am trying to add a Buy column as follows:
 `df$Buy <- ifelse(df$Frequency > 1, 1, 0)` 
before executing the function.
I do not know if this is right way to get the values.
My head for `df` after `getDataframe` is

```
    ID       Date  Amount Recency Frequency  Monetary 
1207779 2016-06-22 2112.00       8        20 1576.7725
2455590 2016-06-26 1064.00       4        16 1074.8400
2660337 2016-06-21 1870.00       9        20 1616.1700
 257997 2016-06-22  616.00       8        22  684.8968
 963883 2016-06-27  703.12       3        16  626.1125
1124489 2016-06-21  594.15       9        18  752.2011
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post the code which is giving the error.

Comment: The error is: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Buy' not found. This is because the Buy column is not present. I cant figure out with what filtering should I generate the buy column. The link of the blog mentions the code here (http://www.dataapple.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/CLV_rcode.txt). My code to call the function: dfProbRF <- getPercentages(dftry,c("Recency","Frequency"))

Comment: Please post the R code not the error message.

Comment: Try this:

 Buy<-rep(0,nrow(dftry))
 dftry<-cbind(dftry,Buy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Buy<-rep(0,nrow(dftry))
dftry<-cbind(dftry,Buy)
```

Comment: But after executing getPercentages I'm getting the dataframe to be empty

Comment: thats because in function getPercentages  this is the filter criteria : "b<-b[b$Buy==1,-1]". And you have defined Buy column with '0' value. You have to assign something to the Buy column based on what you want to do. Something like this : dftry[dftry$Amount > 1000 , ]$Buy<-1